# Start process does not work with VSIXInstaller.exe

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, vsix

I am trying to run the process and wait until it is closed.
When I run VSIXInstaller like below it works:

```
$pathToTheExtension = $path + "VS2012.Ext.vsix"
VSIXInstaller.exe $pathToTheExtension
```

But when I run it through the Start-Process VSIXInstaller does not get $pathToTheExtension as an argument.

```
$pathToTheExtension = $path + "VS2012.Ext.vsix"
$result = $(Start-Process -filePath "VSIXInstaller.exe" -argumentList $pathToTheExtension -Wait)
```

How should I pass the path to the vsix file through the Start-Process?

Below is the result of running Start-Process.

[image]

**EDIT**

I check command line parameter for the running VSIXInstaller process from the Process explorer and it seems correct for me.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" "C:\VS2012.Ext.vsix"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to surround the argument value with quotes.

```
$pathToTheExtension = '"{0}VS2012.Ext.vsix"' -f $path;
$result = Start-Process -FilePath "VSIXInstaller.exe" -ArgumentList $pathToTheExtension -Wait -PassThru;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it leads to the same result

Comment: Does $path have a trailing slash? If not, you'll have to add one between the file path and the file name (right after the {0}).

Comment: $path is valid because I am able to run it using VSIXInstaller.exe $pathToTheExtension